# Using parent values in a tpl function of a helm subchart

Tags: kubernetes-helm

Let's say that I have a Helm chart named "child" with the following `values.yaml`

```
name: "John"
greeting: "Hello {{ .Values.name }}"
```

And a template `test.yaml` with the following contents:

```
result: {{ tpl .Values.greeting $ }}
```

If I run the `helm template .` command, I get this output:

```
---
# Source: child/templates/test.yaml
result: Hello John
```

Now I have a "parent" chart that depends on the "child" subchart. It is declared in the `Chart.yaml` as this:

```
dependencies:
  - name: child
  version: "0.1.0"
  repository: "file://charts/child"
```

The `values.yaml` of the parent chart contains:

```
rename: "Wilson"
child:
  name: {{ .Values.rename }}
```

If I run the `helm template .` command from the parent chart directory, I get this error:

```
Error: cannot load values.yaml: error converting YAML to JSON: yaml: invalid map key: map[interface {}]interface {}{".Values.rename":interface {}(nil)}
```

I would like to get the output:

```
---
# Source: parent/charts/child/templates/test.yaml
result: Hello Wilson
```

Is there any way to pass the value "rename" from the parent to the child subchart?

**NOTES**:

- I don't want to use globals or yaml anchors
- I cannot modify the child subchart
- The "rename" value should be kept, because it is used in other parent templates

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible, even if you could modify the child chart.

Helm doesn't give the parent chart any control over what values get passed to child charts.  It is always the contents of the `child` values with the `global` values merged in.  Nothing in the template code or the `Chart.yaml` can modify this at all.

Even if you could modify the child chart, the usual approach to this involves using the Helm `tpl` function, but at the point the child chart could see this value, the parent value has been hidden from it already.

In the parent chart, if you just want to avoid this duplication, you can see the `.Values.child` and can use that like any other values.

```yaml
# parent/templates/test.yaml
resultFromParent: {{ .Values.child.name }}
```

It may be possible to preprocess the values file or use another tool that allows other constructs there.  One tool I'm familiar with is [Helmfile](https://helmfile.readthedocs.org) which does allow you to use Helm-style templating in constructing values for Helm charts; it also allows you to install multiple charts in parallel, which can get around some cases of wanting "umbrella" charts.